# Where I can find the actual current for my circuit?

Tags: batteries, current-measurement

I started from a very basic circuit. An LED, a resistor, and a power source. I need to choose a resistor to make sure the LED will not burn out (series circuit). My power source is WayinTop Breadboard Power Supply Module. I chose 5 V as the output voltage. The LED's forward voltage is 3 V and the maximum current is 20 mA.

I calculated the resistance as R = V/I = (5 V - 3 V) / (20 × 10<sup>-3</sup> A) = 100 Ω. I tried and it works well. It seems perfect, eh? *But* when I think twice, the current 20 mA is just a number from a specification, not from the actual current value.

Where I can get the actual current? I checked the power supply menu, and it says the maximum current output could be 700 mA. The actual power source is from six Duracell MN1500 1.5 V batteries, which I use as input (9 V) for the power module and they never mention their current (I know the battery use mAh). So how can I ensure the current value is proper in my circuit?

Comment: You said that the LED's maximum current is 20 mA - if that is really the Absolute Maximum current, you should plan for a somewhat lower current.  LEDs don't really care what current you use, as long as it it below the Absolute Maximum.   Using a lower current will result in a dimmer LED.  I find that 5 - 10 mA is adequate for indicator lights, and had to drive some green LEDs with less than 1 mA to get them adequately dim.

Answer (score 3):

> So how can I ensure the current value is proper in my circuit?

Measure it!

If you have a multimeter you have two choices:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS2AFC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. How to measure current using an ammeter and a voltmeter (with known resistor).*

**Current measurement**

- Select the DC current measurement range - start with a high range in case you make a mistake and change to a more sensitive range if all appears OK.
- Connect the probes into the correct sockets.
- Wire the multimeter **in series** with the LED.
- Read the meter.

**Voltage measurement across the resistor**

- Select the DC voltage measurement range. Select the next range above 5 V - usually 20 V.
- Connect the probes to the correct sockets - usually COM and V.
- Measure the voltage across the 100 Ω resistor.
- Calculate the current from Ohm's Law, \$ I = \frac V R \$.

That's it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of my intentions is to protect my LED. So is it ok I just remove the LED and make only the resistor and power source left at the circuit (in a close circuit)? and then check Voltage or amp with a multimeter? If it is ok. then to determine the value of resistance, I need to choose several resisters with different R to try. Is this the best practice in the real world?

Comment: You can do that but it doesn't tell you much. When you remove the LED you now have 5 V across the resistor instead of 2 V. With a 5 V supply and 100 Ω you will read  50 mA. You can measure the voltage across V1 at any time and see if the voltage changes when R1 and D1 are connected.

Comment: "want to protect the LED" : get the LED datasheet, get the minimal forward voltage (not the typical, they can differ quite a lot) and use it when calculating the resistor value. Also, bear in mind that the resistors, as well as the power supplies, have some finite accuracy and you should account for it. You may as well want to have an additional margin of error, in order to keep the whole circuit safe from other possibilities (e.g. high temperature). That's why most electronic elements (LEDs included) are generally used well below their maximum ratings. A 20mA LED works pretty well at 3-7 mA.

Answer (score 3):

The actual number for LED current depends on the brightness the design needs. There are a few ways to find it. Also note that you should never exceed the maximum current for the LED (which is found in the datasheet)

If you have a meter, then put the probes across the resistor, and measure the voltage. The current through the LED and resistor is

$$ V/R=I$$

so if you had a 100Ω resistor, and 1.251V across the resistor, that would be 12.51mA of current

Comment: Thank you. Let's assume I want to save my LED. Before my measurement, could I just keep a resistor and power source in the circuit?

Comment: Start with high value resistors and work your way down to low value resistors

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  As you might be aware, the forward voltage of an LED can vary from part to part and over temperature.  A resistor will have a tolerance as will your power supply voltage.

So your calculation is for the "nominal" current.  If you have data on how the Vf of the LED will vary from part to part and over temperature and how the other parts of your circuit will vary, then you can calculate the range current that you can expect.

But to find the actual current in your circuit you would have to measure it.  A digital multimeter with a current input would be the right tool for the job.

You put the meter and leads in the position for current measurement and put the meter in SERIES with the LED.  That will give you the actual current in your circuit vs. the calculated estimate.

You could also measure the voltage across your resistor and use Ohm's law to find the current, but the accuracy of the resistor will contribute some possible error.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, you don't actually care about the current being 20mA.  You care that the current doesn't exceed the maximum current for your device.  Design for 15mA, and if you're a few percent off, and the LED is bright enough, it's still good enough.

My concern would be that your calculations are based on a \$V_f\$ of 3V, but a red LED will be closer to 2.1V.  If this is the case, your current is too high.  Better to design to about 75% of the max current.  Your devices will live longer.

In fact, if you know the voltage on either side of the resistor, and you know the value of the resistor, then you KNOW the current going through the diode.  Kirchoff's Current Law says the current through the resistor and the diode must be the same.  You can measure the voltages with a $7 multimeter.  Of course, if you have a multimeter, you can also measure the current,  but you'd have to rewire the circuit to do that.  Also, many beginners use multimeters wrong in current measurement mode, and can easily blow a fuse you may not be able to replace.